# Where did this equation come from ∠I+ ∠E = ∠A+ ∠D?

Tags: optics

$\angle I +\angle E=\angle A+\angle D$

Angle of incidence + angle of emergence = angle of prism (Normally $60^\circ$) + angle of deviation.

If their sum is not equal,we made personal error in doing an experiment with prism. Please make sense of this equation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following diagram shows the prism with the incoming and outgoing light rays.

[image: Prism]

If you follow the incident light ray in, it gets bent by an angle $\theta_1 = i- r_1$. If you follow the light ray where it leaves the glass, it gets bent again by an angle $\theta_2 = e - r_2$, so the total deviation is:

$$ \begin{align}
D &= \theta_1 + \theta_2 \\
  &= i + e - (r_1 + r_2)
\end{align} $$

For the next step look at the triangle formed by the top of the prism and the light ray, and note that the internal angles must add up to 180°. So:

$$ A + (90 - r_1) + (90 - r_2) = 180 $$

and a quick rearrangement gives:

$$ A = r_1 + r_2 $$

Now substitute for $r_1 + r_2$ in our first equation and we get:

$$ D = i + e - A $$

or:

$$ D + A = i + e $$

Comment: Thanks, though sadly I can't claim this is an original answer as you'll come across it in any introductory optics course.

Answer (score 0):

An[image]
Please check this answer it is simpler one and easy to understand

Comment: Hi and welcome to Physics SE. Please, read that we don't like images for formula. Images should only be destined to diagrams and phootographs, but not text. Among the main reasons: some people can't see them properly, and the searcher cannot index the formuals if they're on a picture. Please, type the formulae manually.

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Comment: To reinforce the previous comments: your answer may be correct but it is not useful in its current format and as a result is unlikely to attract much attention.  Please take a few moments to go through the basic MathJax tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference